# Uninstall a specific python

Tags: python-3.x

I have installed two python3.6

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4/bin/python3
/Users/me/anaconda3/bin/python
```

`/Users/me/anaconda3/bin/python` was set as default by system

```
$ which python
/Users/me/anaconda3/bin/python
$ which python3
/Users/me/anaconda3/bin/python3
```

If I run `pip uninstall`, the default would be removed which was intended to keep.

How to uninstall the other one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly answer your question: `pip3 uninstall`

`pip3 ...` to do pip for the python3 you've got installed...

`pip3 -V` for example should output the path to where Python 3 is installed